# Spring MVC file upload and public directory

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a folder like "downloads" (full path: `"C:\tomcat\downloads"`).

This is the folder where I throw all the uploaded files. Now I want to access them like this one:

`<a href ="localhost:8080/exampleproject/downloads/image.jpg"> Clickme </a>`

In this folder "downloads", can be anything.

The only question is what should be done to make public folder. At the moment I can save the sent files to disk and delete them. However, I want to access them like above.

It depends on the configuration of spring or tomcat server? Some examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use `<mvc:resources>`

Like

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:/absolute/path/to/image/dir"/>
```

This can be more easier and faster.
For further information, check here 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Answer (score 2):

when read

```
<a href ="examplelink"> Clickme </a>
```

the browser will send Http Request , method GET to link "examplelink". So, in the server we need create the controller catch this GET Request . Example:

```
<img src="image/getimage.html?fileName=${product.imageName }" alt="" title="" width="100" height="100" class="thumb" border="0" />
```

we will have the request

```
http://localhost:8080/somwthing/image/getimage.html?fileName=1409028722025-7d932ec9-18c4-4d17-a61d-557aa8de7970.jpg
```

in the server, we create the controller catch this request , example .

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/image")
public class ImageController {

/**
 * Download single file using
 * @throws IOException 
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/getimage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImage(@RequestParam(value="fileName", required=true) String  fileName,HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("C:\\tomcat\\downloads\\"+ fileName);
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out);
    out.close();
}
```

}

Please notice that read the file from other place in system will make many risk about sercurity. Example When deploy you app to cloud , you can not create a folder like C:\tomcat\downloads