# Spring save uploaded file as public resource

Tags: spring, server

What is the general approach to storing public images on file system?
I have an `endpoint` on the server to save the file. But what I do not understand is how to make it publicly accessible so that I do not have to create endpoint for these public files(I think it would be unnecessary overhead)? Do I need to add some separate file server? 
My web app architecture is:

```
Angular.js client
     |
Node.js client server
     |
Spring backend on separate server
```

What I want to achieve is something like

```
<img src="localhost:8000/public/images/myImage"/>
```

I came to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762201/2764414) answer, but is making endpoint really the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can save image to any path but not necessary to webroot. You can read the image from that directory while showing them.

**ImageController.java**

```
 package com.expertwebindia;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller
    public class ImageController {
        private String path = "E:/uploads/";
        @RequestMapping(value = "/image/display",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public byte[] helloWorld(@RequestParam String name,HttpServletResponse response)  {
            System.out.println("Show is invoked");
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            File file;
          byte arr[]={};
          try{
                 file = new File(path+name);
                  if(file.isFile()){
                      System.out.println("File is found");
                  }
                  else{
                      name = "no-image.jpg";
                      file = new File(path+name); 
                  }
              arr= new byte[(int)file.length()];
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
              fis.read(arr,0,arr.length);
          }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(e);
          }
          return arr;
        }
    }
```

In JSP where need to display need to put `<img>` tag with following. Note I have used JSTL tag here so you need to add JSTL jar to WEB-INF/lib and add taglib to JSP page.

```
<img alt="" src="<c:url value="/image/display?name=${image_name}"/>"/>
```

[Learn more about Spring MVC file upload](http://www.expertwebindia.com/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store images in your application resource folder, try this:

A. Resource Mapping (all directories inside this folder will be accessible):

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

B. Add this in jsp pages:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<img src="<spring:url value='/resources/profile-pictures/${user.profileImage}'/>" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
```

**Note:** All the uploaded images will be stored under `src\main\webapp\resources\profile-pictures` directory.

C. Disable Security:

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
```

D. Method to save Image:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile file, Principal principal) {
    String webappRoot = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
    String LoggedInUser = principal.getName();
    User user = userService.findLoggedInUser(LoggedInUser);
    //System.out.println(user.toString());
    try {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
             BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()));
             File destination = new File(webappRoot + "/resources/profile-pictures/ProfileImage"+user.getName()+".jpg"); // something like C:/Users/tom/Documents/nameBasedOnSomeId.png
             ImageIO.write(src, "png", destination);
             System.out.println("users profile Pic is stored at "+user.getProfileImage() + "UserPassword :" +user.getPassword());
             user.setProfileImage("ProfileImage"+user.getName()+".jpg");
             userService.update(user);
             System.out.println("Image is stored at "+ user.getProfileImage());
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured" + e.getMessage());
        return "redirect:/account/upload?success=false";
    }
    return "redirect:/account/upload?success=true";
}
```

PS: This is not the ideal solution, but works for learning purpose. I am also looking for free image storage. I came across Amazon S3 but it requires credit card, then there is Box, Dropbox. But I found this [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/java_integration) quite interesting.

PPS: You can see my demo app [here](https://github.com/RawSanj/spring-tiles-sample-app).